# Tbl_Strata count by distinct individual vs rows

Tags: gtsummary

How can I use tbl_strata and get the output to show counts by distinct individual rather than rows?

Also, how can I change the order that displays for the variable I am putting in the by= section in tbl_summary?

I have a long table AND a wide table with one row per patient. Not sure how to apply the wide table to this code. I can apply the long table but getting row counts instead of distinct patient counts.

I have included an example of the Long table I have and the wide table and what I would like the output to look like in the picture.

Example code:

```
#Wide Table Example
df_Wide <- data.frame(patientICN =c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
                 ,testtype =c("liquid", "tissue", "tissue", "liquid", "liquid")
                 ,gene1 =c("unk", "pos", "neg", "neg", "unk")
                 ,gene2 =c("pos", "neg", "pos", "unk", "neg")
                 ,gene3 =c("neg", "unk", "unk", "pos", "pos"))


#Long Table Example
df_Long <- data.frame(patientICN =c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3)
                 ,testtype =c("liquid", "tissue", "tissue", "liquid", "liquid")
                 ,gene =c("Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene3", "Gene1", "Gene2")
                 ,result=c("Positve", "Negative", "Unknown","Positive","Unknown"))


#Table Categorized by testtype and result for long table

df_Long %>%
  select (result, gene, testtype)%>%
  mutate(testcategory=paste("TestType",testtype))%>%
  tbl_strata(
    strata=testtype,
    .tbl_fun = 
      ~.x %>%
      tbl_summary(by=result,missing="no")%>% 
      add_n(),
    .header= "**{strata}**, N={n}"
  )

##above is giving multiple Rows per patient counts
```

[image]

Comment: Please update your post with a minimal reproducible example (aka code I can run on my machine), and include sample output of what you'd like to see.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're after? You can install the bstfun pkg from my R-universe: https://ddsjoberg.r-universe.dev/ui#packages

```r
library(gtsummary)
library(dplyr)

#Long Table Example
df_Long <- data.frame(patientICN =c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3)
                      ,testtype =c("liquid", "tissue", "tissue", "liquid", "liquid")
                      ,gene =c("Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene3", "Gene1", "Gene2")
                      ,result=c("Positive", "Negative", "Unknown","Positive","Unknown"))


tbl <- 
  df_Long %>%
  tidyr::pivot_wider(
    id_cols = c(patientICN, testtype),
    names_from = gene,
    values_from = result,
    values_fill = "Unknown"
  ) %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with('Gene'), ~factor(.x, levels = c("Positive", "Negative", "Unknown")))) %>%
  tbl_strata(
    strata = testtype,
    ~ .x %>%
      bstfun::tbl_likert(
        include = starts_with("Gene")
      )
  )
```

[image]
<sup>Created on 2022-10-06 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to substitute bstfun? My work computer wont let me download this package which is where I would be doing most analysis.

Comment: It's just a wrapper for tbl_summary(). You can read the source code on GitHub and copy if you'd like

Comment: Thank you! I found the github folders confusing. Any chance you could write the code with the bstfun package substituted? Thanks so much